# SPD 2013: Access Denied - failed to run workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, permissions, designer-workflow

The user initiating the workflow has 'contribute' permission for this list, however, she is also included in another group with 'read' permission.  I thought the higher level permission would take precedence? Do user need to have contribute at site level? Currently, users have **read** permission at site level and **contribute** permission at list level.

I also checked the site features and **Workflows can use app permissions** is enabled.

Error message received:

[image]

The workflow is very simple:
[image]

I also read this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225073/what-permissions-are-required-to-start-a-workflow?rq=1) suggesting to run workflow manually. This option is already enabled. So something else is preventing the workflow to run. 
[image]

Comment: Check if the user has write permissions for the Workflow History list.

Comment: @DamjanTomic, yes, I just gave them contribute permission to the Workflow History and Task list associated with the workflow. I read the same thing from this [post](https://pascalonthejazz.wordpress.com/2017/01/26/permissions-required-to-start-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/). I haven't confirm if it works, I got pulled to do something else.  I'll post it here once I've tested or confirmed.

Comment: You can quick check based on the guid which list is giving denied. Probally the workflow history list indeed. http://yoursharepointsite/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List=<the guid>

Comment: Thank you all. Yes, I believe it was indeed the Workflow History. Everything seems to be working again once I gave user `contribute` permission in Workflow History.